# Getting CPU clock time AVAudioEngine

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

How does one get the clock time or sample accurate time on the running AVAudioEngine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> The [`AVAudioEngine`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioEngine_Class/index.html) class defines a group of connected [`AVAudioNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioNode_Class/index.html) objects, known as audio nodes. You use audio nodes to generate audio signals, process them, and perform audio input and output.

For clock and/or sample time, you need to call [`lastRenderTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioNode/lastRenderTime) on a valid `AVAudioNode` instance.

The `lastRenderTime` method returns an [`AVAudioTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioTime_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)AVAudioTime) object. With the `AVAudioTime`, you can retrieve time:

1. `sampleTime` will return the sample time is `sampleTimeValid` returns `YES`.
2. `hostTime` will return host time if `hostTimeValid` returns `YES.

Comment: great thanks. I was wondering if there was a callback similar to TAAE. This works though, cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure which TAAE callback you are talking about, but `AVAudioNode` offers [`installTapOnBus`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioNode/installTapOnBus:bufferSize:format:block:)

Comment: Right, one can just call `installTapOnBus` on an `AVAudioNode` and query its `lastRenderTime` within the callback.

Comment: Something doesnt seem correct with that design. If the function, lets say a sequencer, needs exact sample times, the callback design allows it to happen. The AVAudioEngine design will require something else to trigger the lastRenderTime check, e.g. a timer. That timer wont be accurate to the sample level, hence the creation of the callback structure on TAAE.